# Doesn't quartus II support simulate with a verilog file?

Tags: verilog, simulation, quartus-ii

I want to simulate my module **StreamLight** ,So I create a **Simulatefile** module:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module Simulatefile();

reg clk;
reg reset;
wire[5:0] light;
wire counter;


//monitor motor1($light,"counter=%d",counter);
initial 
begin
     reset=0;
     clk=0;
     #1 reset =1;

     #1000 $finish;
end

always #4  clk=~clk;


StreamLight StreamLight0(.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.light(light),.counterlook(counter));


endmodule
```

then, I set this module as **Top_Level Entity**,and  click **Analysis and Synthesis**.Then comes the error:

"Error: Can't synthesize current design -- Top partition does not contain any logic"

But I still can't simulate, Doesn't quartus II support simulate with a verilog file ?

Comment: It does. To get a better answer, ask a better question. What have you tried beyond writing a Verilog module? What is the error message? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since your top-level entity doesn't have any inputs or outputs, it doesn't do anything visible from outside the chip. So the software optimizes it all away in synthesis.

Comment: hey, don't know you are still around, but while I am compiling the code in this question of mine(https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493047/help-on-writing-test-bench-for-up-counter-in-verilog) on Quartus, if I select testbench module as the top level entity, then the same error in this question occurs. But if I select the main module(`up_counter`) as top level entity, then everything goes very smooth and Quartus figures out to set the clock itself. I was wondering why it is working reverse with in the case of Modelsim. Can this be related to your answer here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create this as a module with clk and reset inputs, then use a vector waveform file to simulate it instead. Waveform simulation support was removed from Quartus after v9, IIRC. I use Quartus II v9.2SP1 from the website, as that has simulation support included with the rest of the program.