# Help on writing test bench for up counter in verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, counter, hdl, modelsim

preamble: I think I have enough understanding of logic circuits and enough experience in programming from other languages(C, python, etc.)

#### However, I am very new at Verilog and also have never used VHDL or any other HDL.

---

I want to design an 8 bit up counter which will count up when CLK pulse hits(rising edge).

My understanding on the design and simulation of such a circuit in Verilog is as follows,

First I should design a module which will be my box with inputs and outputs to do the desired job. Then I somehow have to simulate it using a testbench module(I am not sure about this).

So, I designed a module.

Here is my code:

```
module up_counter(

count,
clk,

);


input clk;
output [7:0] count;
reg [7:0] count;

always @(posedge clk) begin

  count = count + 1;

end



endmodule


module up_counter_tb;

  reg clk;

  wire [7:0] count; 
// I really don't understand why making this a wire instead of a reg, but I saw as wire everywhere.


  up_counter uut(

  .clk (clk),
  .count (count)

  );

  initial begin
    clk = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #10 clk = ~clk;
  end


endmodule
```

The code above compiles fine, and I run the simulation in Modelsim by,

```
vsim up_counter_tb
```

Simulation comes, I pass `clk` and `count` to waveform displayer, I run the simulation, `clk` seems fine, it roams between 1 and 0 nicely. **However**, I cannot observe any change in `count`. Its value is alway `xxxxxxxx`.

To me, my code seems correct. **I assume**, I am using a data type or a flow mechanic very specific to Verilog(or a HDL) in a wrong way.

Any help on pointing the mistake here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You made sure the initial value of `clk` was zero before you started toggling it. Did you do the same for `count`?

Comment: @ThePhoton actually, I wanted to try that, however, adding a `count = 8'b0;` right below the `clk = 0;` statement yields an error of : `** Error: /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/bin/up_counter.v(40): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "count".`

Comment: @toolic it was another thing everybody was using in their example, however, I really don't want to have a reset input on my design, it seems meaningless to me. I am sorry if it sounds silly.

Comment: @toolic I just did the assignment in an `initial` block in main module instead of the inside of test bench module and it worked. Would it be a more preferable way over using your way in your latest comment?

Comment: You should make sure `count` is initialized in the the `up_counter` module, not the testbench. If you don't want a reset input on your design, then you can use an initial block like you did for `clk` in the testbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments on my question, the problem was about not initializing the `count` to a known state.

So, adding a `count = 8'b0` in an `initial` block in the main module(`up_counter`) solves the problem.